# Comparing strings with different length without any standard libraries

Tags: c, arrays, string

I would to write a function which compares the strings case insensitive according to the alphabetical order.

```
char compare(char *x, char *y){
    while (*x != '\0'){
        if (tolower(*x) < tolower(*y)){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (tolower(*x) > tolower(*y)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            x++;
            y++;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

But this function doesn't work well with words that share few first letter (ex. word and wordplay). So I've tried to modify it:

```
char compare(char *x, char *y){
if (len(*x) < len(*y)){
    while (*x != '\0'){
        if (tolower(*x) < tolower(*y)){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (tolower(*x) > tolower(*y)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            x++;
            y++;
        }
    }
//         all n letters are the same (case insensitive), where n is a length of x
    if (*y != '\0') return -1;
}
else {
    while (*y != '\0'){
        if (tolower(*x) < tolower(*y)){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (tolower(*x) > tolower(*y)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            x++;
            y`++;
        }
    }
//         all n letters are the same (case insensitive), where n is a length of y
    if (*x != '\0') return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

But it didn't work. How can I modify this function so that 'wordplay' would be greater than 'word'?

Comment: you can't use `stricmp` right?

Comment: there is a printing mistake, instead of a++ & b++ write x++ & y++ and how len(*x) will works.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not I can't, I just don't want to

Comment: Homework alert.

Comment: @nicomp, It's not homework, I learn C on my own

Comment: OK. I understand.

Comment: @jakes: doesn't it worry you that you have 2 identical loop copied & pasted in your code? that makes the code hard to read & maintain

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it's in order to continue checking until the end of the shorter word

Comment: @jakes why did you delete your question (and my answer) ? if that solved your problem, just accept it, else explain what's wrong and I'll fix it (I had it reopened)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I deleted it by mistake, but canceled it seconds later. It had to be some error, sorry for that. And thank you for the answer!

Comment: I understand better. I was really puzzled about the deletion. I'm glad it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is (almost) okay, it just needs tweaking regarding the problem you raised

```
char compare(const char *x, const char *y){
    while ((*x != '\0') && (*y != '\0')) { // testing y for symmetry
        if (tolower(*x) < tolower(*y)){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (tolower(*x) > tolower(*y)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            x++;
            y++;
        }
    }
 // added conditions to handle shorter/longer strings
 if  (*x == '\0') 
  {
      if (*y == '\0')
      {
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         return -1;
      }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I've removed the test for length, added the logic to handle the cases you mentioned. Maybe it isn't the most optimal code but it does the job (also note that I test the end of x & y strings in the main loop)

I've tested against the result of `stricmp` and I get the same results:

```
void test(const char*a,const char*b)
{
   printf("test %s %s => %d, %d\n",a,b,compare(a,b),stricmp(a,b));
}

int main(void) {
  test("abc","aBcd");
  test("abc","aBcd");
  test("abc","aBc");
  test("abcdef","abC");
  test("abcdef","cdef");

}
```

result:

```
test abc aBcd => -1, -1
test abc aBcd => -1, -1
test abc aBc => 0, 0
test abcdef abC => 1, 1
test abcdef cdef => -1, -1
```